# variable or field 'Function' declared void

Tags: c++

I saw a lot of similar questions or same topics, but no answer for my situation (or I am dumb, don't blame me please). I am a begginer and self - learner, so sorry if I am not skilled enough to answer this question by myself.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Skaiciavimai(double kiek_bulviu, int talkininkai, int & dienos,
    int & visi_talkininkai, double & viso_bulviu,
    double & vieno_vidurkis);

int main()
{
    double atsk = 100, bulves[100], talk[1000], kiek_bulviu = 0, talkininkai = 0;
    int dienos = 0, visi_talkininkai = 0;
    double viso_bulviu = 0, vieno_vidurkis = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        cin >> bulves[i];
        kiek_bulviu = kiek_bulviu + bulves[i];
        if (bulves[i] == 0) {
            i = 1000;
        }
        else {
            cin >> talk[i];
            talkininkai = talkininkai + talk[i];
            dienos++;
        }
    }
    void Skaiciavimai(kiek_bulviu, talkininkai, dienos, visi_talkininkai, viso_bulviu, vieno_vidurkis);
    cout << dienos << endl;
    cout << viso_bulviu;
    cout << vieno_vidurkis;
    return 0;
}
void Skaiciavimai(double kiek_bulviu, int talkininkai, int & dienos,
    int & visi_talkininkai, double & viso_bulviu,
    double & vieno_vidurkis) {
    visi_talkininkai = talkininkai;
    viso_bulviu = kiek_bulviu;
    vieno_vidurkis = viso_bulviu / visi_talkininkai;
}
```

Comment: I hope the answer solves your problem, but in the future, you should specify what is going wrong.  If it is a compile error, copy the error here.  If it is a bad result, state input, expected output and wrong output.  As of now, we have some code with non-english names and the fact that there is an issue.

Comment: Not just in the future, but now, in order to save this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void Skaiciavimai(kiek_bulviu, talkininkai, dienos, visi_talkininkai, viso_bulviu, vieno_vidurkis);
```

Remove the leading `void`. You do not need to specify the return type of functions you call. Adding a return type makes it a function declaration. It should look like this :

```
Skaiciavimai(kiek_bulviu, talkininkai, dienos, visi_talkininkai, viso_bulviu, vieno_vidurkis);
```

Edit: For clarity, I've annotated the initial example.

```
int main()
{
    double atsk = 100, bulves[100], talk[1000], kiek_bulviu = 0, talkininkai = 0;
    int dienos = 0, visi_talkininkai = 0;
    double viso_bulviu = 0, vieno_vidurkis = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        cin >> bulves[i];
        kiek_bulviu = kiek_bulviu + bulves[i];
        if (bulves[i] == 0) {
            i = 1000;
        }
        else {
            cin >> talk[i];
            talkininkai = talkininkai + talk[i];
            dienos++;
        }
    }

    /*void*/ Skaiciavimai(kiek_bulviu, talkininkai, dienos, visi_talkininkai, viso_bulviu, vieno_vidurkis);
//    ^^^^ Remove this void

    cout << dienos << endl;
    cout << viso_bulviu;
    cout << vieno_vidurkis;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe it could be a great solution, but I am doing some kind of tasks, where void type is given and cannot be edited. Unfortunately, this line should be left as it is :(

Comment: @Adversas I'll edit my question to clarify. The line cannot remain how it was, it is simply not legal C++.